# Terraform AWS provider upgrade issue with RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

Trying to upgrade AWS provider to version 4, but getting the following error in RDS module:

```
Error: Conflicting configuration arguments
│
│   with module.my-instance-mysql-eu[0].module.rds.module.db_instance.aws_db_instance.this[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/my-instance-mysql-eu.rds/modules/db_instance/main.tf line 47, in resource "aws_db_instance" "this":
│   47:   db_name                             = var.db_name
│
│ "db_name": conflicts with replicate_source_db
```

Answer (score 5):

The error is stating that the `db_name` attribute conflicts with the `replicate_source_db` attribute; you cannot specify both attributes, it must be one or the other. This is also mentioned in [the Terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance#replicate_source_db).

If you are replicating an existing RDS database, the database name will be the same as the name of the source. If this is a new database, do not set the `replicate_source_db` attribute at all.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered a similar issue with the `engine` & `engine_version` variables:

```
│ Error: Conflicting configuration arguments
│ 
│   with module.production.module.replica_app_db_production.aws_db_instance.db,
│   on modules/rds/postgres/main.tf line 36, in resource "aws_db_instance" "db":
│   36:   engine                      = var.engine
│ 
│ "engine": conflicts with replicate_source_db
╵
╷
│ Error: Conflicting configuration arguments
│ 
│   with module.production.module.replica_app_db_production.aws_db_instance.db,
│   on modules/rds/postgres/main.tf line 37, in resource "aws_db_instance" "db":
│   37:   engine_version              = var.engine_version
│ 
│ "engine_version": conflicts with replicate_source_db
╵
```

I found a good example of a solution here: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds/blob/v5.2.2/modules/db_instance/main.tf

And I managed to solve this with the below conditions:

```
  # Replicas will use source metadata
  username       = var.replicate_source_db != null ? null : var.username
  password       = var.replicate_source_db != null ? null : var.password
  engine         = var.replicate_source_db != null ? null : var.engine
  engine_version = var.replicate_source_db != null ? null : var.engine_version
```

If `var.replicate_source_db` is not null, then the username/password/engine/engine_version will be set to null (which is what we need as these variables **cannot be specified for a replica**). And if it is not a replica, then we will have the variables set accordingly :)

You can add the same for the `db_name` parameter:

```
db_name       = var.replicate_source_db != null ? null : var.db_name
```